# How to solve return value of stored function call in Hibernate with MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jboss

I am trying to fetch data from MySQL stored procedure in hibernate . I have a `custom_query.xml` file , and `DAO.java` file

**stored procedure in MySQL :**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SET_NETWORK`(
    IN TO_CREATE BIGINT,
    OUT CREATED BIGINT
)
BEGIN
     SET CREATED = (SELECT COUNT(VNR.ID) FROM NETWORK_TABLE VNR);
    WHILE (CREATED < TO_CREATE) DO
      INSERT INTO NETWORK_TABLE (ACTIVE) VALUES(0);
      SET CREATED = CREATED + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

and i am trying to execute the SQL query from hibernate with following code :

```
 <sql-query name="Network_getFreeNetworksForDomain" read-only="false" callable="true" cacheable="false"><![CDATA[
        { ? = CALL SET_NETWORK(?,?) }
    ]]></sql-query>
```

and in DAO.java file , i am using `Network_getFreeNetworksForDomain` for calling the SQL query :

```
@Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    public List<Network> getNetworksForDomain(Domain domain) throws DataAccessException {
        Long domainId = domain.getId();
        if (domainId == null) {
            domainId = 0L;
        }
        return (List<Network>) getSession().getNamedQuery("Network_getFreeNetworksForDomain")
                .setLong("dId", domainId).list();
    }
```

but i am getting following excretion while deploying the file in to JBoss

```
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't set IN parameter for return value of stored function call.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3294) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3272) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3314) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setLong(PreparedStatement.java:3330) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:]
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.setLong(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:229)
        at com.dao.entity.NetworkHibernateDAO$1.createCallableStatement(NetworkHibernateDAO.java:169) [dao-impl-6.4.0.jar:]
        at com.dao.hibernate.transaction.HibernateUtils.execute(HibernateUtils.java:106) [dao-impl-6.4.0.jar:]
        at com.dao.hibernate.transaction.HibernateUtils$1.doInConnection(HibernateUtils.java:74) [dao-impl-6.4.0.jar:]
        at com.dao.hibernate.transaction.HibernateUtils$2.execute(HibernateUtils.java:91) [dao-impl-6.4.0.jar:]
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.doWork(SessionImpl.java:1987) [hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        ... 51 more
```

and

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [S1009]; error code [0]; error executing work; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: error executing work
```

Any suggestion ? How to solve this kind of errors ?

**Update :**

In DB2 and PostgreSQL this is working fine with

```
 <sql-query name="Network_getFreeNetworksForDomain" read-only="false" callable="true" cacheable="false"><![CDATA[
            { ? = CALL SET_NETWORK(?) }
        ]]></sql-query>
```

but getting same exception mentioned above . so i have added `CALL SET_NETWORK(?,?)` with two parameter with mys stored procedure .

Answer (score 0):

> { ? = CALL SET_NETWORK(?,?) }

It' seems you need 2 parameters and you provided only one

> .setLong("dId", domainId)

I'm not sure your code is able to find the "dId" parameter, maybe you should use the index instead, you can have some sample [in the official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html)

Comment: Previously it was only one parameter  `{ ? = CALL SET_NETWORK(?) }` and getting same exception. So i thought ` my stored procedure` in MySQL ha` IN `and `OUT` value . So i have added `? ?` . If i use only one parameter in `DB2` , `PostgreSQL` it is working . but getting exception in MySQL .